# Define starting line number when using mcode.sty to display Matlab code and referring to the code

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, code, matlab

I want to include parts of my Matlab code in my LaTeX document using mcode.sty. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, dvipsnames,cmyk]{report}
\usepackage{listings}   % Is this package necessary?
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks]{mcode}
\begin{document}
Figure~\ref{fig:binarysearch} doesnt work!
\begin{figure}
\label{fig:binarysearch}
\lstinputlisting{pics/met/binarysearch.m}
\caption[Matlab code for the half-interval search method]
    {Matlab code for the half-interval search method}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to define which line number I want to start on for each included code section? Let's say I want to start on line 6. How is this accomplished? The default is (naturally) 1.

I've placed the code in a figure environment, and I want to refer to it as a figure. However, referring in the text to the figure doesn't work. The compiled file writes `??` instead of the figure reference.

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Comment: I read your answer, @Jubobs, but I didn't really get the hang of it. What specifically is the difference between mcode and your package? Is it possible to explain it with a few sentences?

Comment: There wouldn't be enough space in a Stack-Overflow comment `:p` I refer you to section 2 of the [`matlab-prettifier` doc](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf), in which you will find a point-by-point comparison of the alternatives (`mcode`, `minted`, etc.). Basically, `matlab-prettifier` aims to be easier to use and more consistent than `mcode`.

Comment: @Jubobs: When using `mcode`, there seems to be less space per line in LaTeX compared to Matlab. I've fittet my code into one line in Matlab, but the text must be on two lines in my document. Is this the case for `matlab-prettifier` too?

Comment: That has little to do with `mcode` or `matlab-prettifier`; rather, it depends on the font (family, size, etc.) and the text width you use; you can use the `listings`' option called `linewidth` to tweak the latter to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves the first question:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=6]{{pics/met/binarysearch.m}}
```

`firstnumber` defines the starting line number.

The second question: Wrong order of the code. The following code is correct:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \lstinputlisting[firstnumber=6]{pics/met/binarysearch.m}
    \caption[Matlab code for the half-interval search method]
        {Matlab code for the half-interval search method}
    \label{fig:binarysearch}
\end{figure}
```